# What does a "//" in the path represent in an Angular Typescript import statement?

Tags: angular, typescript

I auto generated a module using the ng client `ng g module app-routing --flat --module=app` with the flat option and I noticed that it created an import statement like this:

`import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';`

I noticed that the path is prefixed with `.//` instead of `./` but I couldn't find a reference to the double slash in the documentation.

Is that an absolute reference or some sort of escape syntax?  Is this a typescript syntax?

Comment: Pretty sure it represents a bug in CLI tool.

Comment: it doesn't seem to throw an error with that path however..

Comment: Sure why would it, `//` is interpreted as `/` in URL, etc (except for protocol).

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey, so what you're saying that the module was successfully imported?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com yes it seems to correctly import.